# set favicon to maven-javadoc-plugin generated javadoc file

Tags: java, maven-3

I can set window title using following code in "`maven-java doc-plugin`".

```
<configuration>
     <windowtitle>name</windowtitle>
</configuration>
```

but I  cannot set "favicon" to my java doc

Comment: I am deploying some Javadoc within another web application over which I have zero control.

In this other web application, favicon.ico is placed in "/img/favicon.ico".

The Javadoc tries to retrieve favicon.ico from "/favicon.ico".

Comment: @leopal it is the same question :P

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question and found the following is my observation.

1. First of all, there isn't any ready-made solution in `maven-javadoc-plugin` which will allow you to add a custom favicon.ico in your Javadoc.

But the good thing is:
I also found out that in `maven-javadoc-plugin` you can modify it to use your custom `doclet` implementation for generating Javadocs.

Now, what is `doclet` ([More details here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#overviewcomment))?

From the above link,

`Javadoc Doclets
You can customize the content and format of the Javadoc tool's output by using`doclets`. The Javadoc tool has a default "built-in"`doclet`, called the standard`doclet`, that generates HTML-formatted API documentation. You can modify or subclass the standard`doclet`, or write your own`doclet`to generate HTML, XML, MIF, RTF or whatever output format you'd like`

So basically you can customize what your Javadoc can generate, you can use more information on customizing the doclet in below mentioned links.

1. [Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112123/creating-javadoc-html-pages-that-use-a-favicon) about which class to modify to generate custom Javadocs.
2. Once you customize the doclet, then you can use it in your `maven-javadoc-plugin` as mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, creating your own doclet can be very challenging, and is not well supported by the JDK in Java 8 and later.

If you are using Maven, an easier way would be to use the [Google Maven Replacer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) plugin to modify the output after it is generated, as in the following example:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>target/site/apidocs/**/*.html</include>
                            </includes>
                            <regex>false</regex>
                            <replacements>
                                <replacement>
                                    <token><![CDATA[<head>]]></token>
                                    <value>
<![CDATA[
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon/icon.png">
]]>
                                    </value>
                                </replacement>
                            </replacements>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```